# MySQL SUM while keeping Summed Data Seperate

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to build some reports, querying a sales table, I have a issue where using SUM and Group by, but still wanting to use the original lines.

For example:

```
Select StockCode, SUM('Sell' * Qty) as Total from 'Sales'
Group by StockCode
```

What i would like is to display the results as a SUM, But i want to also retain the Qty.

So the output would be something like:

StockCode    Qty    Total.

I can obviously run some PHP to do the calculation easy enough, but i was trying to complete as much as possible in SQL Queries to avoid unnecessary cluttered code.

Is there a simple way to do this, or would you advise just doing the calculations in PHP.

Table Example:

```
StockCode   Qty  Sell
1234       2      1.99
5468       1      0.99
2456       2      2.99
1234       3      1.99
5648       1      2.99
2546       2      4.99
2456       3      2.99
```

Sell is Per Item

Example:

```
StockCode   Qty  Sell    Total
1234       2      1.99   3.98
5468       1      0.99   0.99
2456       2      2.99   5.98
1234       3      1.99   5.97
5648       1      2.99   2.99
2546       2      4.99   9.98
2456       3      2.99   8.97
```

Results example:

```
1234       5      1.99   9.95
5468       2      0.99   1.98
2456       5      2.99   14.95
```

Comment: Couldn't `Sell` possibly be different for each grouped row? What value do you want to show in your result in that case? Qty could be represented by `SUM(Qty)`, since the SUM sums up the grouped entries beneath it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to do this:

```
SELECT StockCode, Sell, SUM(Qty) AS Quantity_Sold_At_This_Price, SUM(Sell * Qty) AS Quantity_x_Price
FROM sales
GROUP BY StockCode, Sell
```

The result:

```
| StockCode | Sell | Quantity_Sold_At_This_Price | Quantity_x_Price | 
| 1234      | 1.99 | 5                           |             9.95 | 
| 2456      | 2.99 | 5                           |            14.95 | 
| 2546      | 4.99 | 2                           |             9.98 | 
| 5468      | 0.99 | 1                           |             0.99 | 
| 5648      | 2.99 | 1                           |             2.99 |
```

Comment: How not to consider it is the question.

Comment: Sell seems to be depending on Stockcode which does not meet the second normal form.

Comment: Thanks, I do like this method, as i can also filter out the different sell values. I will be including RRP and Sell, So this would highlight whats been sold at less than RRP. 
Straight away this listed the same code 5 times with different sell values, Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: As long as you include the column in both GROUP BY and SELECT you're good.

Answer (score 0):

it may be problem in **"quote"**, you can try this

```
Select StockCode, SUM(`Sell` * `Qty`) as Total from `Sales`
Group by StockCode
```